# loadJSON not loading <select> value

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery with the loadJSON plugin. In my form, text fields load fine, but select fields don't get their value set. Below is an example:

```
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="member_id" value="" id="member_id">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" id="last_name">
    <input type="text" name="middle_name" value="" id="middle_name">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" id="first_name">
    <select name="gender" id="gender">
<option value='M'>male</option>
<option value='F'>female</option>
</select>
</form>
<script>
    var data='{"member_id":"6346","last_name":"Turtle","first_name":"Myrtle","middle_name":"The","gender":"F"}';
    jQuery('form').loadJSON( jQuery.parseJSON( data ) );
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/issues/detail?id=9

Comment: Thanks! I made the change suggested there and it fixed the problem. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

MelanciaUK solved this in her comment, so I thought I would put it here as an answer

It looks like this is a known issue: [code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/issues/detail?id=9](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-load-json/issues/detail?id=9)

The solution described there is to change the loadJSON code as follows:

```
case 'select-one':
case 'select':
    for (var i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
        element.options[i].selected |= element.options[i].value == value;
    }
    break;

case 'text':
```